# Assigning String Larger Than Destination Array

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory, scanf

When using scanf() to get an input string larger than the array it is being assigned to, how is the compiler assigning those extras characters to memory? I know when assigning a value out of bounds I am basically assigning a value to memory I have not allocated properly. Is this happening in the background when I do the former?

Comment: @l'L'l If I understood that correctly, if the string is larger, the compiler will throw out '\0' to make room? Does that imply the other letters will be "thrown out" or will the compiler attempt to assign those characters to memory, resulting in an error?

Comment: It's ok in C only if the length of the string is exactly the same as the size of the array; `char s[3] = "abcd"`; is illegal.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490805/why-does-gcc-allow-char-array-initialization-with-string-literal-larger-than-arr#comment25317587_13490908. You can, however, do `char s[] = "abcd"` and the compiler should be able to figure out the size from my understanding.