# Why am I getting extra char when printing an array

Tags: c, arrays

I am new to C and I'm getting confused about printing arrays.

Consider this simple code:

```
char myName [5] = "tamir";
printf("My name is %s" , myName);
```

The output of this is "tamirH", with extra H at the end.

But when I declare this array like this  `char myName [6] = "tamir";`  (now the array is declared with 6 chars and "tamir" is made out of 5 chars) I don't see the extra "H".

Why is this happening? Is this related to the string terminator in C or am I confused?

Comment: "tamir" is a string of *6* characters long. Remember that strings re terminated with a special `'\0'` character.

Comment: Related: [Why does gcc allow char array initialization with string literal larger than array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490805/why-does-gcc-allow-char-array-initialization-with-string-literal-larger-than-arr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char myName [6] = "tamir";
```

will work. *And to avoid human errors, it would be even better to simply declare char myName[] and let the compiler allocate memory for you.* (comment suggested by @fassn ) The string literals are converted in a static char array adding also a NULL.  You need to reserve space for NULL as well. "tamir" is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `{'t', 'a', 'm', 'i', 'r', 0}`. The very definition from `ISO/IEC 9899` is so, [`6.4.5p5  String literal`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

> In  translation  phase  7,  a  byte  or  code  of  value  zero  is  appended  to  each  multibytecharacter sequence that results from a string literal or literals.

Comment: And to avoid human errors, it would be even better to simply declare `char myName[]` and let the compiler allocate memory for you.

Comment: @alinsoar What a funny mistake, I was sure that In C you can't declare an array as `myName[]` and let the compiler allocate memory for you as @fassn said. It really makes things clear now. I will accept your question when I will be able to (cant before 10 minutes). Have a great day