# how does printf know the end of a string when the null terminator is not part of the string?

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[10] = "testonetwo";
    printf("str [%s]\n", str);
    return (0);
}
```

I tried printing that string `str` and expected `undefined behaviour` but it printf `str` normally.

Comment: Sometimes undefined behavior looks similar to working properly.

Comment: I like the concept of "expecting undefined behaviour" :-).

Comment: `char str[10] = "testonetwo";` is **invalid** and won't work in C++. Also see [Why is the phrase: "undefined behavior means the compiler can do anything it wants" true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032551/why-is-the-phrase-undefined-behavior-means-the-compiler-can-do-anything-it-wan)

Comment: @StephenNewell but it works properly everytime.

Comment: If I had a _wild_ guess at what may cause it to run fairly consistently: Your `char str[10]` is really, in essence, a `char*`. It points to the string literal `"testonetwo"` which _is_ null terminated, and stored in the data/text section of your executable. When `printf` starts to read this string, it may be hitting the literal's null terminator, despite it being outside of the bounds of what `str[10]` suggested. This is undefined behavior still (and more wonk will show up down the line), but overall I would guess that your code would stay consistent with just what you've shown.

Comment: @Rogue: `str` does not point to a string literal. What often happens in practice, in the absence of optimization, is that `str` is created on the stack and initialized with the ten bytes “testonetwo”, and the following byte happens to be a null byte because this is a simple program that has not cluttered the stack with additional data.

Comment: @JasonLiam True, but this question is about C where the initialization is perfectly valid, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490805/why-does-gcc-allow-char-array-initialization-with-string-literal-larger-than-arr

Comment: @Rogue You're misunderstanding things. `char str[10]="testonetwo";`  is equivalent to `char str[10]={'t','e','s','t','o' ,'n','e','t','w','o'};` -- an on-the-stack (not any section, assuming the declaration is at block scope) array (≠ pointer) without the nul terminator.

Comment: @nielsen: The question was originally tagged with C++ as well as C.

Comment: This is kind of the same thing as blowing up your own car on purpose then ask why one tire landed on your lawn and not in your neighbour's garden. First of all, who cares. Then as for why, well... probably there were padding bytes inserted after your 10 byte long array and maybe they had value zero? Or maybe we are writing out of bounds into the stack frame, killing canaries left and right. Who knows. Now what are we to do with that information? Store a secret message there?

Comment: @YounessAsserare I'm not angry? Although some thousand beginners before you already created similar "spectacular" programs and insisted on knowing why their programs didn't misbehave when they invoked undefined behavior. [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Comment: @YounessAsserare One of the hardest lessons to learn in programming — many programmers never learn this — is that there is a huge difference between a program that works, versus one that works *for the right reasons*.  It is possible for a program to (seem to) work hundreds of times, even though it contains glaring bugs.  Thus you can not use "it works" as any kind of proof that "this program is correct".

Comment: *how does printf know the end of a string when the null terminator is not part of the string?* It turns out this is a meaningless question.  In C there is *no such thing* as a "string when the null terminator is not part of the string".  All strings contain, by definition, a null terminator.  An array of characters without a null terminator is just an array of characters, it is not a string, and therefore `printf` cannot print it reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does printf know the end of a string when the null terminator is not part of the string?

`printf` does not know where the array `str` ends. If the call `printf("str [%s]\n", str)` is implemented with an actual call to a `printf` implementation (rather than optimized by the compiler to some other code), then `str` is converted to a pointer to its first element, and only this pointer is passed to `printf`. `printf` then examines memory byte-by-byte. For the first ten bytes, it sees elements of `str`. Then it access memory outside of `str`. What happens then is usually one of:

- There are additional non-null bytes in memory, and `printf` writes them too, until it finds a null character.
- There is a null byte in memory immediately after `str`, and `printf` prints only the bytes in `str`.
- The memory `printf` tries to access is not mapped, and a segment fault or other exception occurs.

If the compiler did optimize the call into other code, other behaviors may occur. The C standard does not impose any requirements on what may happen.