# No warning when char array initializer too long by 1

Tags: arrays, c, char, initialization, string-literals

When I try to compile the following:

```
int main() {
    char a[4] = "1234";  // This string is length 5, no warning
    char b[4] = "12345"; // This string is length 6, produces a warning
}
```

I get a warning about "initializer-string for char array is too long" or some such only for the second line. does anyone know if this is intentional? Why would the first not produce a warning? I tried both with gcc and clang.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does gcc allow char array initialization with string literal larger than array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490805/why-does-gcc-allow-char-array-initialization-with-string-literal-larger-than-arr)

Comment: How did you compile this?  You might need to pass some flags to produce warnings.

Comment: On OpenBSD, `clang -c test.c` yields `test.c:3:17: warning: initializer-string for char array is too long [-Wexcess-initializers]`.  It might be different with `gcc` on GNU / Linux - although `-Wall` should really enable it.

Comment: @Emoun No. I know about that. But my question is about why there is a warning only if it is too long by at least 2, not by 1. It should either warn in both cases, or not warn in both, no?

Comment: @MartinBaulig That is my question: why does it warn for line 3 and not for line 2?

Comment: @Baruch Because in C, `char[n]` is an array of `n` characters, just like `int[n]` is an array of `n` integers.  In fact, there isn't even anything in the language that dictates that a `char *` is NUL terminated.  For the compiler, a `char *` is just a pointer - it doesn't care about size.  Only on line 3, the 5 characters "12345" cannot possibly fit into an array of size 4 - hence the compiler warning.

Comment: @MartinBaulig The string literal `"1234"` is however always nul terminated and this is guaranteed. The reason why there's no warning is because of a weird quirk in the C language, left behind since the old "fixed string" days of ancient Unix. And this is a FAQ question by now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C opposite to C++ you may initialize a character array with a fixed size with a string literal when the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literal  is not stored in the initialized array.  In this case the array will not contain a string.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization_

> 14 An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
> literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.
> **Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size)
> **initialize the elements of the array**.

So in this declaration

```
char a[4] = "1234";
```

there is no room in the character array for the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literal.

As for this declaration

```
char b[4] = "12345";
```

then it breaks the requirement that

> 2 No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not
> contained within the entity being initialized.

because there is used the initializer `'5'` (that is not the terminating zero character) for a character not contained in the array `b`.

A C++ compiler will issue an error for the both declarations.